# Angular2 muti-select local reference

Tags: angular, multi-select

in my Angular2 app I'm using a multi select input:

```
<select class="form-control" name="attendees" #attendees multiple>
   <option *ngFor="let person of people" 
       value="{{person.id}}" 
       [selected]="isAttending(person)">
         {{person.firstname}} {{person.lastname}}
   </option>
</select>
```

With other input element I can use the local reference, here #attendees, to pass the value to a function (e.g. when a button is clicked).
I'm not really sure how to fetch the values of such multi selct input within my local reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `ngModel`:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="attendeesModel" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="attendees" #attendees multiple>
```

In component try this to log and see if it works:

```
onChange() {
    console.log(this.attendeesModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<select id="attendees" name="attendees" ngModel #attendees="ngModel"
        class="form-control" multiple>
    <option *ngFor="let person of people"
            value="{{person.id}}" [selected]="isAttending(person)">
        {{person.firstname}} {{person.lastname}}
    </option>
</select>

{{ attendees.value }}
```